# Simplifying GPA calculator

Tags: java, beginner

I'm only two weeks into learning Java and just finished creating my first program.  I have a feeling I've added unnecessary things, but not sure. I'd like someone to take a look at it and let me know if there are ways to simplify or approach the code.  Basically, I'm just trying to create a simple GPA calculator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GpaCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c1;
        double gpa;
        double g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6;

        g1 = 0;
        g2 = 0;
        g3 = 0;
        g4 = 0;
        g5 = 0;
        g6 = 0;

        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 1?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g1 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g1 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g1 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g1 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g1 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 2?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g2 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g2 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g2 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g2 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g2 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 3?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g3 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g3 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g3 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g3 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g3 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 4?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g4 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g4 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g4 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g4 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g4 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 5?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g5 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g5 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g5 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g5 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g5 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class 6?");
        c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'A') {
            g6 = 4;
        }
        if (c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'B') {
            g6 = 3;
        }
        if (c1 == 'c' || c1 == 'C') {
            g6 = 2;
        }
        if (c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'D') {
            g6 = 1;
        }
        if (c1 == 'f' || c1 == 'F') {
            g6 = 0;
        }

        gpa = (g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6) / 6;

        System.out.println("Your GPA is " + gpa + ". ");

        if (gpa > 3.00) {
            System.out.println("Gret job, you're on your way to success.");
        } else if (gpa > 2.00) {
            System.out.println("You did OK, but better than average.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You didn't do too well. You should look into getting a tutor.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, both `Grade` and `Class` (`GradedClass` to avoid confusion with `java.lang.Class`) make sense as enums.

```
enum Grade {
    A(4),B(3),C(2),D(1),F(0);

    private final int value;

    Grade(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

enum GradedClass {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "class " + (ordinal() + 1);
    }
}
```

This will allow a much simpler calculation loop :

```
    public double calculateGpa() {
        return calculateTotal() / GradedClass.values().length;
    }

    private double calculateTotal() {
        double total = 0d;
        for (GradedClass gradedClass : GradedClass.values()) {
            Grade grade = userInterface.askGradeFor(gradedClass);
            total += grade.getValue();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Note that I've hidden away the scanner behind a UserInterface interface, in order to separate calculation from UI code.

It's implemented by the ConsoleUI class :

```
class ConsoleUI implements UserInterface {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public Grade askGradeFor(GradedClass gradedClass) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("What is your grade for {0}?", gradedClass));
        String input = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0);
        return Grade.valueOf(input.toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public void presentGpa(double gpa) {
        if (gpa > 3d) {
            System.out.println("Great job, you're on your way to success.");
        } else if (gpa > 2d) {
            System.out.println("You did OK, but better than average.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You didn't do too well. You should look into getting a tutor.");
        }
    }

}
```

The Main class simply ties everything together :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface ui = new ConsoleUI();
        GpaCalculator gpaCalculator = new GpaCalculator(ui);

        double gpa = gpaCalculator.calculateGpa();
        ui.presentGpa(gpa);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would improve your code as following :

- Look at your code, you'll notice the repetition of the same piece of code (print a question => scan for input => analyze the input), it means you could write a method for that.
- If you want to ask for one more grade, you'll have to create a new variable, etc. I would store grades in an array.
- Actually, I'm not even sure I would store them in an array: just sum the grades, and then divide it by the number of grades
- Lower case the user input, so you don't have to test for lowercase and uppercase.
- use `if ... else if` instead of several `if`
- In your case, you initialize the grade with 0, and store 0 when user type `f`. It is not necessary to deal with this case.
- You don't deal with E grades?

The code would look like something like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GpaCalculator {
    private final static Scanner MY_SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final static int NUMBER_OF_GRADES = 6;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GRADES; i++) {
            sum += askForGrade(i);
        }
        final double gpa = (double) sum / NUMBER_OF_GRADES;

        System.out.println("Your GPA is " + gpa + ". ");

        if (gpa > 3.00) {
            System.out.println("Gret job, you're on your way to success.");
        } else if (gpa > 2.00) {
            System.out.println("You did OK, but better than average.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You didn't do too well. You should look into getting a tutor.");
        }
    }

    private static int askForGrade(final int index) {
        System.out.println("What is your grade for class " + (index + 1) + "?");
        char c1 = MY_SCANNER.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);

        switch(c1){
            case 'a':
                return 4;
            case 'b':
                return 3;
            case 'c':
                return 2;
            case 'd':
                return 1;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you could improve the prompt to accept only real grades (in your code and in mine, user can provide any character).

Comment: +1 Gud explanation. But best practice says that try to make single exit point for every method.

Comment: Yes, you are absoluty right, I edited my answer in consequence.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal I disagree, [using multiple exist points can make your code more readable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/41071).

Comment: @svick I agree with you, but I read everywhere the single exit thing (there's even a PMD rule), but I think it's less readable too. In this case, I think readability is not much impacted.

Comment: @ssssteffff you can use **switch** with a *'char'* instead of `if .. else if ..`

Answer (score 0):

- First off try to think all the logics and behavior of your `GpaCalculator` and seperate them in classes.
- Like bowmore suggested you could use `enum` which is flexible for your code.

This is my version for your code.

- Also try to think about the [exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) that can be raised from the code such as `IllegalGradeException`.

**GradeCalculator class**

```
    package com.se.cr;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GradeCalculator {

        private final int NUMBER_OF_CLASSES;
        private Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Default constructor
        public GradeCalculator(){
            this(6); // By default number of classes are 6
        }

        // Customize constructor
        public GradeCalculator(int NUMBER_OF_CLASSES){
            this.NUMBER_OF_CLASSES = NUMBER_OF_CLASSES;
        }

        public double calculateGPA(){
            final double GPA = this.calculateSum() / NUMBER_OF_CLASSES;
            return GPA;
        }

        protected double calculateSum(){
            double sum = 0.0;
            for(int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; i++){
                sum += this.gradeValue(i);
            }
            return sum;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param classNumber 
         * @return grade of that particular <code> classNumber </code>
         */
        protected double gradeValue(int classNumber){
            System.out.print("What is your grade for class " + classNumber + " ? ");
            char gradeChar = myScanner.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

                while(gradeChar < 'a' || gradeChar > 'f'){
                System.out.println("Wrong choice"); // raise an exception here and handle it
                System.out.print("What is your grade for class " + classNumber + " ? ");
                gradeChar = myScanner.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            }
            return this.toGradeValue(gradeChar);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param grade
         * @return numeric representation of <code> grade </code>
         */
        public double toGradeValue(char grade){
            double gradeValue = 0.0;
            switch (grade) {
                case 'a': gradeValue = 5.0; break;
                case 'b': gradeValue = 4.0; break;
                case 'c': gradeValue = 3.0; break;
                case 'd': gradeValue = 2.0; break;
                case 'e': gradeValue = 1.0; break;
                case 'f': gradeValue = 0.0; break;
            }
            return gradeValue;
        }
    }
```

**Teacher class** [ you can also make this a separate class other than making it a main class, as bowmore suggested ].

```
    package com.se.cr;

    public class Teacher {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GradeCalculator calculator = new GradeCalculator();
            final double GPA = calculator.calculateGPA();

            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
            teacher.takeDecision(GPA); 
        }

        /**
         * Teacher will take decision on the basis of <code> GPA </code> 
         * @param GPA 
         */
        protected void takeDecision(final double GPA){
            System.out.println("Your GPA is " + GPA);
            if (GPA > 3.00) {
                System.out.println("Gret job, you're on your way to success.");
            } else if (GPA > 2.00) {
                System.out.println("You did OK, but better than average.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You didn't do too well. You should look into getting a tutor.");
            }
        }
    }
```